# when and why do we use two or more ros::NodeHandle for one Node?

Tags: ros, ros2, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

could you please explain when and why two or more ros::NodeHandle object are used in a program?
could you please give some experimental example for these cases?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309008/when-and-why-do-we-use-two-or-more-ros::nodehandle-for-one-node?/) by [MahShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/37854/mahshah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-11-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-21**:
You tagged this with `ros2`, but afaik ROS 2 doesn't (yet) have a `NodeHandle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you are using ROS1:
The NodeHandles define how names are resolved in the ROS system. See [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Names) for details.

One typical use case is the following:

Create a regular and a private NodeHandle:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh();
ros::NodeHandle pnh("~");
```

Topics, services, etc. typically use the regular NodeHandle `nh`. This ensures that topics etc. are always relative to the nodes namespace.

A private NodeHandle makes the nodes name part of the namespace. This is good for parameters, as they are typically tightly coupled to the node itself and thus having them private avoids collisions.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rajendra](https://answers.ros.org/users/47029/rajendra/) on 2020-01-16**:
Thank you!